# Python 3: How to convert a bytearray to an ASCII string

Tags: python, python-3.x, arrays

I have the following `bytearray`

```
bytearray(b'S\x00t\x00a\x00n\x00d\x00a\x00r\x00d\x00F\x00i\x00r\x00m\x00a\x00t\x00a\x00.\x00i\x00n\x00o\x00')
```

It should spell out `StandardFirmata.ino` however, I can't figure out how to decode it.

Here is what I have tried:

```
print(str(board.sysex_list)) #Appears to just return a string that looks identical
print(board.sysex_list.decode()) # Returns just S
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrong encoding.

```
3>> bytearray(b'S\x00t\x00a\x00n\x00d\x00a\x00r\x00d\x00F\x00i\x00r\x00m\x00a\x00t\x00a\x00.\x00i\x00n\x00o\x00').decode('utf-16le')
'StandardFirmata.ino'
```

But that's not ASCII.

Comment: Any good resources on this mysterious `bytearray` object? The documentation did not help much.  To me it just looks like a string of bytes that returns `ints` when indexed....

Comment: That's because that's what it is: a sequence of bytes. If you want to turn it into text then you need to decode it using the appropriate encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was not specifying a decoding. All I had to do was change `decode` to `decode('utf-16-le')`